# Can I put timer on my React router component so it loads after other router finished animation?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, settimeout, react-animated

This is my loader component (using framer motion), css doesn't matter.

```
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import classes from './Loader.module.css';
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from 'framer-motion';

const Loader = () => {
  const [removeDice, setRemoveDice] = useState(true);
  const [displayNoneDice, setDisplayNoneDice] = useState(false)
  setTimeout(() => {
    setRemoveDice(false)
  }, 2000)

  setTimeout(() => {
    setDisplayNoneDice(true)
  }, 6000)
  return (
    <Fragment>    
      <div className={classes.loader__container}>
      <motion.div className={classes.dice__container}
      initial={{x: '-95vw'}}
      animate={{x: 0, rotate: 2160}}
      transition={{duration: 4}}>
        <AnimatePresence>
          {removeDice && (
            <motion.div className={classes.dice}
            animate={{x: 4, scale: 500}}
            transition={{duration: 4.5, delay: 4.5}}
            exit={{opacity: 0, display: displayNoneDice}}
            >
                <div className={classes.dice__dot1}></div>
                <div className={classes.dice__dot2}></div>
                <div className={classes.dice__dot3}></div>
                <div className={classes.dice__dot4}></div>
                <div className={classes.dice__dot5}></div>
            </motion.div>
          )}
          </AnimatePresence>
      </motion.div>    
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default Loader;
```

and this is my App component. How can I load my 'GamesPage' component after 'Loader' finished animating? Would think only of set timeout because I would put custom number when animation in 'Loader' is finished.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import Loader from './components/loader/Loader';
import { Route, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import GamesPage from './components/main-page/GamesPage';

function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Routes>
          <Route path='/' loader={<Loader />} element={<Loader />} />
          <Route path='games' element={<GamesPage />} />
      </Routes>
      
    </Fragment>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can use the `onAnimationComplete` prop on the `Loader` component to trigger a function that will change the route to the `GamesPage` component.

Comment: am trying to implement but it i don't know how and where to type your comment into code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.